# LinearLayout is slow to move, if I load one image in ImageView

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-imageview, android-sliding

I have a list, it captured moving finger, and you can delete an item by sliding your finger

if  the  image is not loaded  in my container, with ImageView.setImage(), the container moves correctly.

However, if I loaded one image the container moves slowler.

Why is this happening?

Attach images below.

1.moves correctly

[image]

2. not moves correctly
   [image]
   always moves the container from left to rigth

Why is it?
Thanks.

**UPDATE 19/01/2014**
i reduced bitmap to 150 kb and continue equal.

leave my code

```
    objelementos.lnyDatosCliente.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, final MotionEvent event) {



         final  CCliente objcCCliente = lstLista.get(objelementos.posicion);
        CAnimaciones objAnmanim = new CAnimaciones();
        Display pantalla =  afrmGstionClientes.getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        final int ancho = pantalla.getWidth();



        switch ( event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                fdYPrimeroPulsado = event.getRawY();
                fdXPulsadoInicio = event.getRawX();
                fdXUltimaPulsado = event.getRawX();
                iTamanioLnyPulsado =0;

            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:


                        float fdXPulsado = event.getRawX();
                        float fdXMovimiento = fdXPulsado- fdXUltimaPulsado;
                        objelementos.lnyDatosCliente.setVisibility(4);
                        objelementos.lnyDatosClienteToMove.setVisibility(0);
                        objelementos.lnyDatosClienteToMove.setX(fdXMovimiento);
                        iTamanioLnyPulsado =1;



                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:

                float fdXPulsad = event.getRawX();
                float xmov =fdXPulsad- fdXUltimaPulsado;
                fdYUltimoPulsado = event.getRawY();


                        int difx = (int)fdXPulsad- (int)fdXPulsadoInicio;

                        if (difx>120){ 
                            ObjectAnimator animaciion = objAnmanim.CrearAnimacion(objelementos.lnyDatosClienteToMove, xmov, ancho+10, "x", 85);//(xFin-20, ancho+10, 200) ;
                            animaciion.start();


                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                float num = objcCCliente.getposicionXInicio();

                               AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                        getContext());
                                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                                builder.setTitle("!AVISO!");
                                builder.setMessage("¿Estas seguro de eliminar el cliente?")
                                        .setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            CustomAdapterListadoClientes.this.lstLista.remove(objelementos.posicion);
                                            CustomAdapterListadoClientes.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                          }
                                        })
                                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            vol(ancho-10, objelementos.lnyDatosCliente.getX(), objelementos.lnyDatosClienteToMove, 180, objelementos.lnyDatosCliente);
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                            }
                                        });
                                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                dialog.show();
                                }
                            }, animaciion.getDuration());


                        }else{




                            if (iTamanioLnyPulsado==0){
                                float dify = fdYPrimeroPulsado -fdYUltimoPulsado;
                                if (dify<0){
                                    dify*=-1;
                                }

                                if (dify<10){
                                float fddondeesta = objelementos.lnyDatosCliente.getY();
                                ObjectAnimator animaciion = objAnmanim.CrearAnimacion(objelementos.lnyDatosCliente, fddondeesta-1, fddondeesta, "x",50);

                                animaciion.start();
                                Cnavegar objNavegar = new Cnavegar();
                                AfrmHigthModificationCliente afrmModificacion = new AfrmHigthModificationCliente(true, objcCCliente,afrmGstionClientes);
                                objNavegar.RemplazarFragmento(R.id.rtlAltas, afrmModificacion, "AfrmHigthModificationCliente", afrmGstionClientes.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
                                }
                            }else{

                                 if (difx>0){
                                     vol(xmov, objelementos.lnyDatosCliente.getX(), objelementos.lnyDatosClienteToMove, 180, objelementos.lnyDatosCliente);
                                 }else{
                                     vol(xmov, objelementos.lnyDatosCliente.getX(), objelementos.lnyDatosClienteToMove, 180, objelementos.lnyDatosCliente);
                                 }


                            }


                        }


                break;
            }


                return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is it slow when debugging or also in normal runtime?

Comment: +1 for using Moderat album cover ;-) How are you creating your image ? For example, are you decoding a Bitmap to a correct size ? Is the List scrolling slow or the delete action ?

Comment: I use bitmap,with size  going of the camera,the part slow, occurs to action move  rigth to left

Comment: is slow normal runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve my problem of slow , which resided not in the size of the image
I used two linear layout changing your visibility associated with this adapter to change it to visible or invisiblo gone. 
he adapter had to rewrite the  code again and has this was because my problem. 
now only work with linerar layout unchanged visibility, position and only my application I run to perfection

thanks for your help everyone

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [ViewHolder](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html) pattern?
Are you loading your images on another thread?

For load images I use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library.

Comment: Picasso resolved your issue? so please check my answer as correct :)

Comment: You say that you get the image to full resolution, maybe you should try reducing the bitmap resolution.